# Virtual Driver: how to force resolutions for debugging

Tags: c++, directshow, video-capture

I'm working on a Virtual Driver (Directshow filter) and I'm using graphedt to test and debug the filter.

Right now my code supports only the resolution of 320x240 px (hardcoded).
As far as I understand I need to handle the GetMediaType and GetStreamCaps functions to support other resolutions.

Two questions:

1. I'm looking for an example for this but I cannot find it, perhaps I'm using wrong keywords in my websearch
2. how to force a request for a specific resolution in order to test my code using graphedt or any other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for an example for this but I cannot find it, perhaps I'm using wrong keywords in my websearch

Here you go: https://github.com/rdp/open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter/blob/master/vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project/vcam_vs_2010/Filters.cpp#L237

Eight resolutions:

```
if(iPosition < 0) return E_INVALIDARG;
if(iPosition > 8) return VFW_S_NO_MORE_ITEMS;

[...]

pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth      = 80 * iPosition;
pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight     = 60 * iPosition;
```

> how to force a request for a specific resolution in order to test my code using graphedt or any other tool?

Real application will (might) choose among available.

GraphStudioNext offers Ctrl+Shift+M option to choose while connecting.

Otherwise it is typical to pick resolutions/media types in order of enumeration, so the line 237 I highlighted with the link above shows you the way to temporarily override:

```
if (iIndex == 0) iIndex = 4;
```

Comment: Super fast answer! If I'm not wrong the `iPosition` and `iIndex` variables have actually the same meaning: pick the current resolution among the eight available. Having different names did lead me to confusion. I could think `iIndex == 0` as the default resolution? I.e. no one is selected.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+M does nothing on my graphedt (v.9)

Comment: Check actual methods in a linked source code file, I just highlighted the featuring lines. [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) is what you want to use instead of GraphEdit.

Comment: Last question: to support resolutions up to 1920px I changed the lines 127 and 227 editing the number 8 to 24 (24 * 80 = 1920). But GraphStudioNext cannot select a media index greater than 8 (which is the max default). Is my approach wrong?

Comment: There is no limit of 8, perhaps you need to recheck/rebuild the code - you are doing it right.